# Autocomplete ALMOST working on bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

i'm ripping my head out over integrating jquery UI in a bootstrap theme. i simply want to use the Input elements of jquery UI in some places. all the elements i need are working, but not the dropdown/autocomplete

http://codepage.net/test3/?page_id=2

the dropdown button is missing. otherwise it seems to working fine.

removing the    bootstrap.min.js'  on the bottom of the page gets rid of the problem (of course, that's no solution). any idea on how to get this control working? it seems that bootstrap messes up its setup.

why? i look for a really pretty and smooth UI framework for input controls, all controls from one source. but this seems to be a problem

THANKS!

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solve the problem by using:

```
    <script>
      $.noConflict();  
      // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
    </script>
```

to avoid clashes between bootstrap and jquery.

for more info read this : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

there are other solutions for you problem:

1. what version of jquery are you using? I know that older versions of jquery like 10.2 don't have that problem.
2. personaly, I used Kendo-ui auto complete, much more elegant, with no conflicts, here is a link: [Kendo autocomplete](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete)

Good Luck.

Comment: i have used jquery_1.11.1

Comment: please try one of my 3 solutions.

Comment: the problem is solved.  i only had to load jqueryui.js after bootstrap.js  , instead of other way arround. thanks Roy